# 'Se me van encoger' o 'se me van a encoger'

Tags: preposiciones

Me gustaría saber si alguien sabe cuál es la forma correcta de expresar algo que se encogerá:
'Se me van encoger' o 'Se me van **a** encoger'

Comment: Lo que no debes decir es el "se" si no es una parte de ti mismo. Es decir, "el jersey encogerá o podrá encoger" pero el uso del pronombre reflexivo "se" sería erróneo (no se puede decir "el jersey se me encogerá", aunque sea tú jersey).

Comment: @OnaBai, Lo que dices es interesante, pero porque seria erroneo?

Comment: No me parece que el uso de _se_ se ajuste a ninguno de los usos indicados en http://www.elcastellano.org/pronombr.html

Comment: Perdonen, no logro escribir comentarios.
Pero si que se puede usar el "se".
Me tiro en el rio? ... la ropa se me va a encoger.
Si dices: la ropa se va a encoger, no queda claro de que ropa estas hablando.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debería ser 'Se me van **a** encoger'.
Es la misma construcción que 'ir a xxx' para expresar algún evento en el futuro.

Answer (score 3):

Como [bien dice A109201](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/se-me-van-encoger-o-se-me-van-a-encoger#3196), la construcción correcta es ***ir a*** + infinitivo. En el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas [tienes una descripción de esta perífrasis verbal](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=qF8kh8sgID6Ifqj7vG#4):

> **ir a** + infinitivo. Perífrasis verbal que indica que la acción
>   designada por el infinitivo se va a producir en un futuro más o menos
>   inmediato: *«Vas a tener miles de problemas»* (Gamboa *Páginas* [Col.
>   1998]); muy a menudo implica propósito o intención por parte del
>   sujeto: *«Te voy a leer una carta de mi padre»* (Jodorowsky *Pájaro*
>   [Chile 1992]); a veces se emplea con finalidad exhortativa: *«Para
>   empezar, vas a sentarte como un niño bueno»* (Vilalta *Nada* [Méx.
>   1975]); en ocasiones se emplea, especialmente en pasado, para indicar
>   que lo expresado por el infinitivo es un hecho inesperado o
>   inoportuno: *El asunto fue a salir por donde menos se esperaba*. En
>   ningún caso debe suprimirse, en el habla culta, la preposición *a*:
>   (x) *«Pero ¿se lo vas plantear ya?»* (FnGómez *Bicicletas* [Esp. 1982]);
>   (x) *Vamos hablar del asunto.*

Answer (score 1):

Siempre debes colocar la letra "a". Por ejemplo, si te refieres a reducir de tamaño:

> Se me van a encoger las medias
>   Se me va a encoger la ropa en la secadora

*Va* se usa en singular, *van* en plural.

Comment: Creo que el uso del pronombre reflexivo "se" en tu ejemplo no es correcto y debería utilizarse: "me van a encoger las medias" o incluso "encogerán las/mis medias".

Comment: Porque es erroneo el uso del pronombre reflexivo en este caso @OnaBai?

Comment: No me parece que el uso de _se_ se ajuste a ninguno de los usos indicados en http://www.elcastellano.org/pronombr.html